# Flash not appearing first time but appears on page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a piece of code checking the dates submitted in a form are not the same:

```
if params[:statement_end_date] > params[:statement_start_date] 
  flash[:notice] = "End date cannot be greater than start date."
  puts "salary report saved #{flash[:notice]}"
  redirect_to 'statements/listing'
```

The problem is that when i enter two dates that are the same the page is rendered but no flash. When i refresh the page or go to another page the flash appears.

Comment: Which page do you want it to appear on the first time? Can you include the controller action for that page and the params when the request is made (from your log)? A little more detail, for example where the code above appears, would help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash):

> The flash is a special part of the session which is cleared with each
>   request. This means that values stored there will only be available in
>   the next request, which is useful for passing error messages etc.

In other words, a flash notice will never appear on the view you were looking at when it was generated. It will always appear on the *next* view.

If you want to display a message on the same view, you're going to have to create a [partial view](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) that redraws a "status" div in your view based on your `if params[:statement_end_date] > params[:statement_start_date]` condition.